# Вигук Во! і великий палець вгору

Tags: етимологія

Побачив "Видиво" і чомусь подумав "Види + **Во!**". Спробував пошукати, але щось нічого не знайшов про **Во!**.

Я **Во!** розумію як вигук плюс жест, який означає молодець, або добре. Але ж повинно щось бути щодо походження чи точніше визначення. Чи є зв'язок **Во!** з видиво і подібними запитаннями типу печиво ніби печи+**Во!**?

Можна знайти щось щодо самого [жесту](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C). Але чому під час цього жесту кажуть **Во!**?

Основне запитання: Чи є якась інформація про вигук Во! з жестом великого пальця вгору або де можна пошукати щодо цього, якщо інформація достатньо поширена?

Answer (score 4):

Саме слово "во" є питомим - [ЕСУМ IV, 124](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=124): о² (вигук, вказівна частка), [во] "ось", первісно вказівний займенник праіндоєвропейського походження. Є частиною гинших складених займенників: "(в)ото", "(в)осе" та гинші.  "В" у давньоруському "вото" виникло через [протезу](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), а [синкопа](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) "ото" → "от" і дала "вот", тому ні, це не є росіянізмом (брав інформацію [звідси](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/laik#t10373)). Щодо самого походження значіння "выражение одобрения, поощрения, согласия" у "во" - оскільки такі слова, як "ось" чи "он", вживаються "для підсилення кількісної або якісної характеристики кого-, чого-небудь" (["он", СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/on), ["ось", СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/osj)), то точно сказати складно, проте я більше схиляюся до думки, що такий розвій слова в українській мові не був питомим, а набув певного поширення в нашій мові через змосковщення.

А "види + во", "печи + во" - се зовсім не те. [Тут](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/ukrajinskij_pravopis_2007/pravopis_osnovi_slova/pravopis_sufiksiv_imennikovi_sufiksi/12-1-0-311) читаємо таке:

> Суфікс -ив-(о), що вживається для вираження збірних, понять, які означають матеріал або продукт праці, пишемо тільки з и: вариво, добриво, куриво, меливо, мереживо, місиво, морозиво, паливо, печиво, прядиво, але: марево (не матеріал і не продукт праці).

Comment: Додам, що витяг наведено з параграфу 25 правопису (проєкт-99).

Comment: Маєте рацію. Сховаю свою відповідь, як неправильну.

Comment: @Yola, додам, що в [§22.2 правопису 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par22p2) те саме (тільки вжито дієслово «пишеться», а не «пишемо»); і [в §32.2 правопису 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=27) теж по суті те саме (лише трішки переформульовано).

Comment: Правда, автор, схоже, не зможе позначити як правильну.